# ADF Trigger from Storage Event not working

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-storage, eventtrigger

I created a trigger in ADF that would look for Storage Events. I am able to see the blob/files in the trigger but when the files get generated, the ADF pipeline does not start.

I did link the trigger to a pipeline.

Is there a firewall setting or access of some sort that I am missing?

Azure/Microsoft docs dont specify anything in this regard.

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Comment: The Azure account must have either the Owner role or the Contributor role to the storage account, or the Microsoft.EventGrid/EventSubscriptions/Write permission to the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue.

The setup for done right with the appropriate roles as mentioned in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python)

The issue was with ADF. We have a new ADF setup that is connected to a ADO REPO. The change I was making was in a branch and were not being deployed to the LIVE ADF instance.

I disconnected the REPO from the ADF and made the triggers in the LIVE ADF and it worked.

There are 2 ways to trigger ADF from dbt jobs.

1. dbt Webhook --> Azure Function --> Blob --> ADF
2. dbt webhook --> Azure Function --> EventGrid --ADF

The 2nd option seem to be a better alternative as you save on managing and cost for the blob storage. BLOB triggers are also sent to EventGrid. So using EventGrid directly seems better.

Thanks for your help.